# How to Convert Dictionary Values to sets of Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I am trying to solve some graph problems but i am stuck halfway. I have a python dictionary of sets, but i will like to convert the original dictionary values (which are sets) into a dictionary such that each value in the set becomes a key which would have another value of 1. I think this is what is called a nested dictionary - i am not sure.

I looped through the `dict.values()`, assigned to a variable xxx, and used the `dict.fromkeys(xxx, 1)` code and it worked, but i am unable to integrate the result back into the original dictionary.

Here is an example of a dictionary:

```
d = {'35': {'1', '37', '36', '71'}, '37': {'1', '35'}}
```

I want the output to look like:

```
d = {35: {1 : 1, 37 : 1, 36 : 1, 71 : 1}, 37: {1 : 1, 35 : 1}}
```

if you notice, the original dictionary values have become dictionaries of their own, and the apostrophes ('') are off.

Can someone assist me please, or give me pointers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You just need a little bit of list comprehension:

```py
def convert(input):
    return {key: {val: 1 for val in vals} for key, vals in input.items()}

print(convert({'35': {'1', '37', '36', '71'}, '37': {'1', '35'}}))
# {'35': {'1': 1, '37': 1, '36': 1, '71': 1}, '37': {'1': 1, '35': 1}}
```

Comment: BOOM! Thanks a lot. I changed to int(key) and int(val) to convert the strings items to integer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just wrap keys and values with `int`:

```
{int(k):dict.fromkeys(map(int, v), 1) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{35: {37: 1, 71: 1, 36: 1, 1: 1}, 37: {35: 1, 1: 1}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable contributions.